# Custom Grok Pattern for [serverity]MMDD

Tags: logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, grok, logstash-file

I'm a beginner in writing `grok` patterns and I'm unable to figure out how to write custom grok pattern for this

> I0224 22:37:20.377508  2437 zookeeper_watcher.cpp:326] Zk Session
> Disconnected, notifying watchers
>
> "I" being log_severity. and "0224" is in MMDD format.

I've tried to work in https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ with the standard `grok` patterns but I'm unable to seperate log_severity from month and day.

Really appreciate any help or directions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
%{DATA:severity}%{MONTHNUM:month}%{MONTHDAY:day} %{TIME:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{INT:num}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

This is what I've come up with after quite a bit of researching. Hopefully it'll be useful for someone who's looking!